# Understanding Amazon web services free tier

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am very new to technology world. I want to host a website on AWS free tier as I dont have budget right now but I am not getting what their free tier is offering since they are using a bit more technical terms for their components.

Can anybody help me here.

My website will be running on java, postgres, spring etc

Comment: There probably isn't a way to provide general guidance on this, since AWS pricing and free tier qualifications are highly dependent on which collection of services you're using. You'll need to specify which services you want to use and what's confusing about the pricing structure.

Comment: I just want to use like cpu, db, network for accepting and receiving requests etc.. I am not even sure what else I will need to run a website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AWS Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) is designed to allow people to evaluate AWS services. It is not intended for running free websites.

If you want a low-cost means of running a website, take a look at [Amazon Lightsail](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/). It has low-priced options with various components combined in the price.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I just registered for aws free tier. I have created EC2 instance but again I am not sure how to deploy. Can you share any good doc to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I will just extend John's answer

> I want to host a website on AWS free tier

Free tier is intended to evaluate services and easy/low cost startup. For many services (lambda, iot,..) the free tear is pretty much generous, however for EC2 (virtual server) it's limited in terms of resources and time (aws free tear includes a single t2.micro instance for a year)

Be aware the big cloud providers (AWS, Google, Azure, IBM) are not really the cheapest, however you got a lot of values around provided (feature services, resources, geological availability, reliability, security, etc)

You can start small, but not really free in long run.

> My website will be running on java, postgres, spring etc

In theory you could try to fit it all into a free tear t2.micro instance, but then don't expect much of performance. Java needs som RAM space and DB as well.

Answer (score -2):

Although this is not answering your question on AWS free tier, if you want a service which is a bit generous on free tier till you get funds to run the website, use Google Cloud. It give $300, with limits to 8 vCPUs you can spin up per region. AWS will give only 1 vCPU for 750 hours for a year.